# SMS spoofing detection

Tags: phishing, spoofing, sms

Our company uses SMS delivery providers like Nexmo etc. We have noticed some of our recipients have received phishing sms messages from fraudsters where the number/sender name was spoofed to match our company's name.

Is it possible to backtrack theses messages to identify the source? BTW We don't control/have access to recipients phones.

What measures can we take to ensure that such messages can be detected and our number/sender name is not spoofed.

Comment: Short answer: you can't. Only the mobile carriers can.

Comment: Are the fraudulent SMS's pretending to be you AND sent to actual customers of yours? If so, I'd be more worried about customer data being compromised since that would be a spear phishing attempt. Of course this can happen by chance, only you can judge if this is statistically significant enough to be suspicious. Large companies get attempts like these just because of the numbers, a small company is a lot less likely to have customers spear phished purely by random attempts.